# MVC 5 Role based Permissions (Authorization)

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, permissions, roles

I want to implement Role based authorization in mvc 5, i am using asp.net identity 2.0 for user authentication.

Please suggest how to implement this by using authorize attribute or any other possible way.

I also want to store user rights after login and do not want to fetch again and again from database while authorizing on controller action. (Don't want to use Session).

[image]

```
[![Role Permissions stored in DB][1]][1]
```

[image: **Role Permissions stored in DB**]

Answer (score 0):

I probably am not understanding the depth of your question, but I see that your Authorize statement is slightly incorrect.

Try [Authorize(Roles="admin")]
It uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

There's also a Policy Based Authorization. [Authorize(Policy = "Seniors")]

I also found an answer here that may be of interest to you, it speaks of customizing Role Permissions:[create custom authorize attribute](https://forums.asp.net/t/2120932.aspx?How%20to%20set%20permission%20based%20on%20user%20and%20page%20in%20MVC)

The trick will be to assign the User a role, then use the 'Authorize' on the action methods or on the page, or even in the view HTML by testing if the user IsInRole like:
@if(User.IsInRole"admin"){ Add HTML Here  }

And if you do use 'Roles', remember that you can add multiple roles to the 'Authorize' tag something like [Authorize(Roles="admin, staff, user")] etc.